# naming convention of table, model file and model class in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am using cakephp 2.6.9. I have a table named: chat_info and model file: ChatInfo.php and class inside ChatInfo:

```
 <?php
/**
* 
*/
class ChatInfo extends AppModel
{
    var $name = "chatinfo";

}

?>
```

but it shows an error. I searched for this error and found that this is due to naming convention violation in cakecaphp. But whats wrong am I doing here

Comment: Singular/plural is imprtant, see the [CakePHP namimg conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)

Comment: When receiving errors, always post the _complete_ and _exact_ error message, ideally including the stracktrace that should be available for all errors (either on the error page, or in the logs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Model::useTable

As found in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable):

> The useTable property specifies the database table name. By default, the model uses the lowercase, plural form of the model’s class name

Conventions are not intended to be unbreakable rules. They are guidelines which, if followed, make life easier. That does not mean they have to be followed. Using `useTable` it's possible to use any table name, in this case:

```
class ChatInfo extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = "chat_info";

}
```

Two asides, assuming you're not actually using php4:

1. **It is a terrible idea** to set the model name to something other than the actual model name. It's not necessary to set it to anything, since it's designed purpose is php4 compatibility. The name of a model is [the class name](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L716), setting it to something else can easily lead to confusion or unexpected side effects.
2. Declaring variables with `var` is php 4 style, use the features of the version of php in use, i.e. declare variables using [public, protected or private](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Answer (score 1):

if you will rename the table from **chat_info** to **chat_infos** it will be ok

Or if you want to mantain that name for the table then add this in your model:

`$useTable = 'chat_info';`

and your model will be associated to the table chat_info (without plural mode)